# Dijit ValidationTextBox: invalidMessage displayed or not, depending on what the user makes first

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo

I've defined a `dijit.form.ValidationTextBox`:

```
var nameBox = new ValidationTextBox({
    style: 'width: 300px;',
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    regExp: '.{5,50}',
    invalidMessage: 'Name is required and must be between 5 and 50 characters',
    value: dto.name
}, 'name')
```

But the validation isn't working exactly as I would expect. If I go into the field, I enter 3 characters and leave, I get the given message. When I clear the field afterwords, I still get the same message.

However, when I first focus the field and leave it empty, I get the message:

> This value is required

When I, afterwards, enter 3 characters, I have the same standard message, not the custom message I've given.

It seems that the 1st error message that is issues got 'stuck' on the widget. It is some kind of bug, or I've misconfigured something? I'm using **Dojo 1.9.2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**invalidaMessage** is used only for validation issues that does not satisfy the regex condition.
For the "*required= true*" condition, a separate "**missingMessage**" attribute is used. This attribute must be set to be displayed if the field is left empty when required is set to true.

```
var nameBox = new ValidationTextBox({
    style: 'width: 300px;',
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    regExp: '.{5,50}',
    invalidMessage: 'Name is required and must be between 5 and 50 characters',
    missingMessage: 'Name is required and must be between 5 and 50 characters',
    value: dto.name
}, 'name')
```

This will fix the issue.

Comment: Well, yes, the issue is fixed, but have I understood correctly, it's impossible to have distinct missingMessage and invalidMessage? Because the one that was first triggered would be displayed, not that, that applies to current state?

Comment: We can have distinct misingMessage and invalidMessage. But missing message takes higher priority if required is true. So, once data is being written, the validation check will be done for which invalidMessage will be used for failed cases. If you just see the source code of ValidationTextBox.js, you will see that this is the order they have followed. If required, you can write your own overriding validate/validator methods for this. (Check out how to build custom dojo widgets).

Comment: The problem was, the missingMessage was shown even if the widget was not empty.

Comment: That is weird. Maybe some error with the DOM. Did you try it in another browser? ANything you notice on console? 
Actually, "This value is required" is the default message if something is not given. So, hence you got it as required was set true. But it will display only when field is blurred empty. Otherwise the regex will be validated and invalid message will be displayed. (if invalidMessage is not provided, it also takes "This value is required" by default).